# Mobile layout using Azure .NET 4.5, MVC4

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 application and have added mobile views. The mobile views are being picked up on most devices except for _Layout.Mobile.cshtml. When I run locally on various emulators, the mobile layout is picked up correctly but when I run on azure, the mobile layout is not picked up. However, other mobile views are picked up correctly.

This link discusses a similar issues an a workaround in .NET 4.0.

[displaymode for mobile with desktop view for ipad in asp.net mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254604/displaymode-for-mobile-with-desktop-view-for-ipad-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Does this issue still exist in .NET 4.5?

When I attempt to apply the workaround using .NET 4.5, I get the message

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.1.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.dll could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.
```

Answer (score 0):

We are running MVC4 on ASP.NET 4.5 on Azure WITHOUT the workaround/patch and don't have an issue.  You can see the mobile switching at www.drivetime-atlanta.com both _Layout.Mobile.cshtml and index.mobile.cshtml are picked up just fine.